# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text', (xml, python)

Tags: python, xml

I have an xml file,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rpc xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0" message-id="1">
  <edit-config category = "xyz">
    <target category="cooking">
      <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
    </target>
 </edit-config>
</rpc>
```

I want to print author name, I am doing it like this,

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree
tree = ElementTree()
root = tree.parse("test.xml")
print ('Name: ', root.find('rpc/edit-conf/target/author').text)
```

I am getting following error, Is there something I am missing.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

see below

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rpc xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0" message-id="1">
  <edit-config category = "xyz">
    <target category="cooking">
      <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
    </target>
 </edit-config>
</rpc>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
author = root.find('.//{urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0}author')
print(author.text)
```

output

```
Giada De Laurentiis
```

Comment: This worked, but what is the issue with the way I am trying to print author name, like I want to know what mistake I am making ?

Comment: Read about xml namespace. Don't forget to up vote :-)

Answer (score 0):

The tag will be accessable through the following XPATH:

```
a = root.find('./{urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0}edit-config/{urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0}target/{urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0}author')
# or ".//{urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0}author" for skip middle sub elements and find subelements, on all levels.      
Out[7]: <Element '{urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0}author' at 0x7f01f9c1a220>
print(a.text)
```

`xmlns` in rpc tag refers to [XML namespace](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp) (used to prevent conflict when trying to mix XML) and in the XML file at the rool element you see `urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0` as the namespace.

To find proper Xpath step-by-step, try:

```
In [1]: root.find('./')                                                                                                                                                                      
Out[1]: <Element '{urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0}edit-config' at 0x7f01f9c16ef0>

In [2]: root.findall('./{urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0}edit-config/')                                                                                                              
Out[2]: [<Element '{urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0}target' at 0x7f01fa2a4ea0>]

In [3]: root.findall('./{urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0}edit-config/{urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0}target/')                                                              
Out[3]: [<Element '{urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0}author' at 0x7f01f9c1a220>]

In [4]: root.findall('./{urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0}edit-config/{urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0}target/{urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0}author')               
Out[4]: [<Element '{urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0}author' at 0x7f01f9c1a220>]
```

Answer (score -1):

xml tag is `<edit-config category = "xyz">`

code is searching for `'/edit-conf/'`

make them the same and you'll be fine